# R: how to filter within aes()

Tags: r, ggplot2

As an R-beginner, there's one hurdle that I just can't find the answer to. I have a table where I can see the amount of responses to a question according to gender.

| Response | Gender | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 84 |
| 1 | 2 | 79 |
| 2 | 1 | 42 |
| 2 | 2 | 74 |
| 3 | 1 | 84 |
| 3 | 2 | 79 |

etc.

I want to plot these in a column chart: on the y I want the n (or its proportions), and on the x I want to have two seperate bars: one for gender 1, and one for gender 2. It should look like the following example that I was given:

[The example that I want to emulate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VHaH.png)

However, when I try to filter the columns according to gender inside aes(), it returns an error! Could anyone tell me why my approach is not working? And is there another practical way to filter the columns of the table that I have?

```
ggplot(table) +
   geom_col(aes(x =  select(filter(table, gender == 1), Q), 
                y = select(filter(table, gender == 1), n), 
                fill = select(filter(table, gender == 2), n), position = "dodge")
```

Comment: Better to use data argument, something like `+ geom_col(aes(x = Q, y = n, fill = n, data = table[ gender == 1, ] ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Response), y=n, fill=factor(Gender)))+
  geom_col(position=position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your answer does not work, because you are assigning the x and y variables as if it was two different datasets (one for x and one for y). In line with the solution from TarJae, you need to think of it as the axis in a diagram - so you need for your x axis to assign the categorical variables you are comparing, and you want for the y axis to assign the numerical variables which determines the height of the bars. Finally, you want to compare them by colors, so each group will have a different color - that is where you include your grouping variable (here, I use `fill`).

```
    library(dplyr) ## For piping
    library(ggplot2) ## For plotting
    
    df  %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Response, y = n, fill = as.character(Gender))) +
      geom_bar(stat = "Identity", position = "Dodge")
```

I am adding "Identity" because the default in geom_bar is to count the occurences in you data (i.e., if you data was not aggregated). I am adding "Dodge" to avoid the bars to be stacked. I will recommend you, to look at this resource for more information: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html